# Can't get my stored procedure to execute on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I tried creating the most simple procedure and still can't execute.

```
create procedure sp_getinfo()
begin
SELECT * FROM `metals`
end
```

I get this error:

> ERROR  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: It still blows my mind how *bad* error messages are in mySql.

Comment: Unrelated but you shouldn't need the `s surrounding "metals"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getinfo()
  BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM `metals`;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I don't know MySQL too well, I just Googled for a tutorial and found [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx).

Comment: This will work (and a quick Google search would have found it...). The `s are not necessary.

Comment: No problem, every so often I have to answer a MySQL question on StackOverflow to remind me why I use PostgreSQL.